# Conditional JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In a node.js service I wish to perform replace inside a string, where the result string depends on a numerical value inside the original string. I must use `string.prototype.replace` and I must do this in a single step, these are given conditions so please don't ask why.

```
var original = "blah/XX/blah"; //XX stands for 00-99
var regexp = new RegExp(/blah\/(d{2})\/blah/, "g");
var alternate = "mama$1/mia";
var result = original.replace(regexp, alternate);
```

Expected result:

```
XX == 01 => mama/mia
XX > 01 => mamaXX/mia
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: whatever the string you want to return mama(XX)/mia replacing the initial string?

Comment: BTW: you don't need use RegExp constructor in this case as the string passing to constructor is static, not dynamic.

Comment: Use the string match method, and then use an if statement to do different replaces based on the result of that if statement.

Comment: You forgot the ``\`` before `d`. Use `var regexp = /blah\/(\d{2})\/blah/g;`.

Comment: What is the expected output if `XX = 00`? You have not specified expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a non-capturing group and an alternation: `var regexp = new RegExp(/blah\/(?:(01)|\d{2})\/blah/, "g");`

Explanation:

- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, so it doesn't affect `$1`.
- `(?:(...)|...)` is a non-capturing group with two alternatives. The first alternative is saved to `$1`. The second one is not grouped.
- `01|\d{2}` is an alternative. `01` would match both but the regex engine stops at the 1st match.

You can play with that on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d98trrta/).

Comment: Great idea, although your answer gave me the opposite of what I needed. Using your line of thought, this solves the problem:
`var regexp = new RegExp(/blah\/(?:(01)|(\d{2}))\/blah/, "g");`
`var alternate = "mama$2/mia";`

Comment: You do not need to capture `(01)`, you can use `var regexp = new RegExp(/blah\/(?:01|(\d{2}))\/blah/, "g"); var alternate = "mama$1/mia";`

Answer (score 1):

You may leverage a callback method inside `replace` to parse the integer and specify different replacements depending on that value:

```js
var original = "blah/01/blah"; //XX stands for 00-99
var regexp = /blah\/(\d{2})\/blah/g;
var result = original.replace(regexp, function($0, $1) {
  return $1 !== "01" ? "mama" + $1 + "/mia" : "mama/mia";
});
console.log(result);
```

With `/blah\/(\d{2})\/blah/g` we match all substrings starting with `blah/`, then have 2 digits and `/blah`, and then check if the number is more than `1`, we concatenate `"mama"`, number and `"/mia"`. If it is `1` or `0`, we only return `"mama/mia"`.

Just FYI: you had a typo in the regex, `\d` matches a digits, not just `d`.

Comment: true, I missed typing in the backslash before the digit matcher

Comment: I see now what you meant. I updated the answer so now it solves your problem equally well. Using a callback method inside a `replace` is a flexible solution, but you might not need that flexibility here. Anyway, it is more readable than capturing inside an alternation non-capturing group.